# Whatsapp and changing SIM

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

In a while I will be changing operator and SIM card, but not number. I backed up contacts, SMSs, even call logs. But I have no idea how to back up Whatsapp conversations. Do I need to worry? In other words, when I do such a change, do I risk losing my Whatsapp chats or are they linked to the number, implying they will get transmitted to the new SIM with the same number? Or perhaps they are linked to the device, which will also stay unchanged?

Comment: The messages are linked to the devices (ie. they are stored there). Changing your SIM/number does not delete them. If you do not change your number you don not need to worry about anything, the messages will still be on your phone and WhatsApp will continue to work as normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. If you are keeping the number, then you need not worry about your Whatsapp account.

To backup conversations, go to whatsapp settings -> Chat and Calls -> Chat Backups.
You can use Google Drive to backup to your Google account on Android devices.

Although you use your phone number as your account Id, the account is tied to device. You changing carrier has no effect on the account.

Comment: What if I changed phone and wanted to resrore from a backup?

Comment: Either move the Whatsapp folder to the root sdcard directory of you new phone or sign in from the same google account you used to back up to (in case of Google Drive backup). Allow Whatsapp access to your drive when asked during initialization.